# unable to debug the VS.net 2003 application

Tags: visual-studio

When i m trying to debug the vs.net2003 application. It is throwing me error like 'unable to run the application because user does not have admin right,kindly add user in debugger user list.'

Could any one help me on this problem??

Thank you

Comment: VS2003 is not supported on Vista or Win7.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your login credentials to the local debuggers group on your machine, or log in as an administrator.  You don't have rights to attach to the running process at the minute.

Have a link with some details:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa291270(VS.71).aspx